# Using py2exe with tkinter to create a standalone .exe

Tags: python, tkinter, py2exe

I have a calculator program with a tkinter created GUI. I want to package this into a single GUI but using

```
py -3.4 -m py2exe.build_exe calc_gui.pyw -p tkinter -b 0
```

in the command prompt, I get get the error message:

```
The following modules require a minimum of bundle_files option, 
otherwise they will not work (currently bundle_files is set to 0):
         tkinter: 2

Please change the bundle_files option and run the build again.
Build failed
```

I was wondering if there was a way I could package this into a single .exe using py2exe as using -b 2 or 3 works fine but they don't produce standalone .exe's

BTW, this is in Python 3 (which is supported by py2exe)

Comment: Did you try doing what the error message is telling you to do?

Comment: Then it isn't bundled into a single exe, there is about 8 files around it.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `build_bundle option to one`. That will bundle it into one file.

Comment: The error is saying tkinter needs it to be set to 2  as a minimum. I got around the problem by using nuitka eventually

Comment: @SovietKetchup Good job